# How do i return the correct values of to this?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
def activate():

    if(ultrasonic.get_sample() < 10):
        both.turn(power=-70, tacho_units=400, brake=False)
        time.sleep(1)
        bx,by = get_ballxy()
        rx,ry,a = get_robotxya()
        turn_to(brick,bx,by,rx,ry,a)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        move_to(brick,bx,by,rx,ry)
        kickBall(brick,by)  
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        bx,by = get_ballxy()
        rx,ry,a = get_robotxya()
        turn_to(brick,bx,by,rx,ry,a)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        move_to(brick,bx,by,rx,ry)
        kickBall(brick,by,ry)

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
connect()
update_coordinates()
while True:
    activate()
```

Above is the portion of my code. `get_ballxy` and `get_robotxya` return the coordinates of the corresponding objects and the `turn_to` and `move_to` method obviously makes the robot turn to the object and move to it. Values are returned from a server and are stored in a thread as a background process. My question here is how can I ensure that my robot don't take in false values or the same values as previous as I run it in a loop? For example:

- First set of values:

  - Turn to ball move to ball and kick the ball;
  - Wait till ball stops moving then only reread the values to the robot then run this in a loop.

How do I do this? I tried sleeping it `time.sleep(seconds)` it works sometimes then after awhile it goes mad.

Comment: What are false values? What are "same values as previous" and how can they end up in activate()?

Comment: @Simon false values are values that are taken before the ball stop moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to not move/turn/kick while the ball is in motion, try adding this:

```
def activate():
    global x1, y1
    if(ultrasonic.get_sample() < 10):
        both.turn(power=-70, tacho_units=400, brake=False)
    bx, by = get_ballxy()
    rx, ry, a = get_robotxya()

    if sqrt((x1-bx)*(x1-bx)+(y1-by)*(y1-by)) <= 4: #This is the distance parameter, change at will
        turn_to(brick, bx, by, rx, ry, a)
        move_to(brick, bx, by, rx, ry)
        kickBall(brick, by, ry)

    x1, y1 = bx, by

Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
connect()
x1, y1 = 0, 0
update_coordinates()
while True:
    activate()
```

Comment: what do you mean by changing distance by will?

Comment: That's how far the ball can have moved before the robot goes and chases it down. I put 4 in as an example, but I don't know what units bx and by are, so if they are, for example, feet, you might want something more like 0.1.